# change color cells in datagridview programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I trying my way around changing color of cells in `DataGridView` .

I'm a bit new to datagridview and have looked upon many of the question posted here but none seem to work for me.

my final iteration (which still doesn't work) is:

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        DataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        int cellIndex = 0;
        Color c = Color.Gray;
        foreach(var row in  DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList())//.ForEach(row =>
        {
            var cells = row.Cells;
            if (cells.Count > 0) {
                cellIndex = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in cells)
                {
                    DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Style.BackColor = c;
                    //cell.Style.BackColor = c;
                    cellIndex++;

                }
                if (cells[0].Value!= null)
                if ((cells[0].Value as string ).Contains("==="))/*end of section*/
                {
                    c = (c == Color.Gray) ? Color.Transparent : Color.Gray;/*change color at end of section*/
                }
            }
            rowIndex++;
        }
        rowIndex = 0;
```

what can be the problem with my code? 
Is there is any parameter I need to set on True\False in order for the color to change?

**EDIT**
what I do: I want to open new form that only have `DataGridView` to so data and all other uses are with context menu( `MouseButtons.Right`)

**More code**

```
public partial class ResultsDiffForm : Form 
{
    public ResultsDiffForm(DataTable DT)//consatructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        /*Old code goes here ... */
    }
}
```

It should be clearer what am I doing.

Comment: Have you tried using `Styles.Add("style", "value");`?

Comment: Just to clarify, it uses CSS rules: `Styles.Add("background-color", "grey");`

Comment: Where in your code are you doing this?

Comment: @LarsTech Are you talking to me ?

Comment: @DrewKennedy OK , tnanks for the clearifacation :)

Comment: @LordTitiKaka Yes, I am.

Comment: @LarsTech inside the cells foreach

Comment: @LordTitiKaka That's not what I meant.  See the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post where you are calling this code, but the DataGridView control in WinForms is finicky when you try to set the cell properties in the constructor of the form.

Try using the OnLoad override instead:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);

  // your DataGridView code here...
}
```

Comment: I'll post more code to show what I'm doing , please review it

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
DataGridview1.Columns[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

Comment: can you please add some explenation on what is the difference between DefaultCellStyle.BackColor VS Style.BackColor

Comment: have you tried it? Did it work? I have no idea why it works.. it just works for me so I thought I'll show it to you.

Comment: I tried it , but it seems that the problem was (as @LarsTech answered) that I did it inside the form constructor , I cant say what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
                if (cells[0].Value!= null)
                if ((cells[0].Value as string ).Contains("==="))/*end of section*/
                {
                    if(c == Color.Gray)
                    {
                      c = Color.Transparent;                              
                    }
                    else
                    {                 
                       c = Color.Gray;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: you the problem is with how choose the color ?
because I start with gray , yet my table is all white

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowIndex = 0;
        int cellIndex = 0;
        Color c = Color.Gray;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            var cells = row.Cells;
            if (cells.Count > 0)
            {
                cellIndex = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in cells)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Style.BackColor = c;

                    cellIndex++;

                }
                if (cells[0].Value != null)
                    if ((cells[0].Value as string).Contains("==="))
                    {
                        c = ((c == Color.Gray) ? Color.Transparent : Color.Gray);
                    }
            }
            rowIndex++;
        }
        rowIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I cant tell the difference from my code and yours... can you please clearify ?

Comment: the iteration in the foreach is done different. but does it works for you ?